# Node.js fs.unlink deletes locked file when it becomes unlocked on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, fs

If I use fs.unlink to delete a locked file on Windows then the callback is called with an error, as expected.  When I subsequently terminate node the file is deleted.  I am at a loss as to how this might be happening and would prefer that locked files are not deleted.
I should add that it is node that holds the lock so the file is presumably deleted when the lock is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never knew that Windows did this but apparently this is a feature of the DeleteFile SDK function.  Not a lot that node can do about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
fs.unlinkSync('filename.extension');
```

will delete the file only if its unlocked.
in case if the file is used it will give error

Resource is busy